# Using PS layer fx stoke on outside of layer with square corners

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When using the layer style fx > stoke in photoshop is there a way for the stroke to have square right angled corners, whilst having the stoke set to the outside of the layer so it dosnt clip the layer. Normally when you set it to the outside it will give you rounded corners as the image below.

Background - Im using PS CC

[image: red text markup]

Comment: Ivan you rock !!!!! THis exactly did what i wanted, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to achieve this is to create a shape layer and add a stroke to it:

[image]

Then use your image as a clipping mask for the shape:

[image]

Comment: Actually the shape is the one being used as a clipping mask to the photo. Otherwise great solution.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, you can't.

If you want sharp corners you can not use a Layer Style stroke on the outside. You must use other methods - the easiest is probably....

- create a selection the size of the photo
- use `Select > Modify > Expand` to add pixels to the selection (the size of your desired stroke)
- add a layer *below* the photo
- fill the selection with the color you want your stroke.

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly in Photoshop CC, not sure about previous versions:

1. Click on the thumbnail in the layers panel to create a selection
2. Enter quick mask mode by pressing "Q" in your keyboard
3. Go to "Filter" > "Other" > "Maximum"
4. Enter a Radius amount (this will be your border thickness)
5. Select "Preserve: Squareness" and Click "OK"
6. Press "Q" to exit quick mask mode

Answer (score 0):

Like [Scott](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/39764) said, you can't. A quicker and more flexible workaround since Photoshop 21.2 (June 2020 release):

1. In the layers panel, right click the layer and click "Frame from layer"
2. Select the frame layer.
3. In the Properties panel (Window > Properties), choose your stroke width and set stroke type to "outside".